# Firebase Command Line does not open a browser window

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-tools

I'm new to firebase. I installed updated version of nodejs and npm and I installed firebase-tools and commands seem alright but when I enter `firebase login` in command line, It doesn't do anything:

[image]

Comment: Can you try running `firebase login --debug` and pasting the output here so we can try to debug further?

Comment: It just writes header outputs and then waits and waits.
I tried reinstalling firebase-tools but still got mentioned problem.

Comment: [debug] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] Command:      node C:\Users\Peyman-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\bin\firebase login --debug
[debug] Platform:     win32
[debug] Node Version: v0.12.7
[debug] Time:         Fri Apr 15 2016 04:47:31 GMT+0430 (Daylight Time)
[debug] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug]

Comment: This is a strange one. Can you please file this as an issue at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues? It will be easier to try to track down the problem and talk about it there.